# ASPX inserting to MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, parameters

I'm completely new to an programming and I'm having trouble getting my data to `insert` into a table `ticket` is there anything syntactically or logically wrong with this code that should insert the ticket information? I don't get any error but it also doesn't insert the data

```
using (MySqlCommand newercmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO ticket (StudentID, ClassID, TicketTitle, TicketStatus, Module, ExcerciseNumber, TCode, StartingTime) VALUES (Select StudentID from student where GlobalID = @GlobalID, @ClassID, @TicketTitle, '1', @Module, @Excercise, @TCode, NOW()", con))
{
    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GlobalID", globalbox.Text);
    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ClassID", ClassBox.Text);
    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TicketTitle", TitleBox.Text);
    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Module", ModuleBox.Text);
    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Excercise", ExcerciseBox.Text);
    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TCode", TcodeBox.Text);

    newercmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Full  aspx.cs Code here:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"............"))
    {

        string checkglobal = "select count(*) from student where GlobalID= @GlobalID";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(checkglobal, con);

        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GlobalID", globalbox.Text);
        var objectuserexists = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        int userexists = Convert.ToInt32(objectuserexists);

        // if exists do nothing as we already have them stored!
        if (userexists > 0)
        { }
        else
        {
            // does not exists insert into student table
            using (MySqlCommand newcmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO student (GlobalID) values (@GlobalID)", con))
            {
                newcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GlobalID", globalbox.Text);

                newcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }


            {

                //insert into ticket table
                using (MySqlCommand newercmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO ticket (StudentID, ClassID, TicketTitle, TicketStatus, Module, ExcerciseNumber, TCode, StartingTime) VALUES (Select StudentID from student where GlobalID = @GlobalID, @ClassID, @TicketTitle, '1', @Module, @Excercise, @TCode, NOW()", con))
                {
                    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GlobalID", globalbox.Text);
                    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ClassID", ClassBox.Text);
                    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TicketTitle", TitleBox.Text);
                    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Module", ModuleBox.Text);
                    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Excercise", ExcerciseBox.Text);
                    newercmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TCode", TcodeBox.Text);

                    newercmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it may be my con.open/close. Testing now to try and figure that out

Comment: Not necessarily your issue, but you have a conn.close() inside the using block.  When you have a using block you don't call conn.close; it is called for you when the object is disposed (which is what 'using' does).

Comment: Check your connecting to the correct database and check the rowsAffected returned from `newercmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`